# Undefined Index in Post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, undefined-index

I have no idea why I am getting this weird error!

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: refId in /var/www/echo.php on line 5

I am getting Console output, but cant echo `refId`. Have I done anything wrong here?

```
<?php
    $rollUrl = 34;
    $refId = $_POST['refId'];
    echo $refId;
?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url:'echo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'refId': "<?php echo $rollUrl ?>" },
        success: function(response){
            console.log('Getting response');
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: If that's all one file, then the `$_POST` is getting referenced before a POST is sent.  Add a conditional around that block to check `if (count($_POST) > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Please see the comments in the code below:

```
<?php
$rollUrl = 34;

//Only try to process POST if there is something posted *and* refId exists
if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['refId'])) { 
  $refId = $_POST['refId'];
  echo $refId;
  //Exit after echoing out the refId so that the HTML below does not also get returned.
  exit();
}
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url:'echo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'refId': "<?php echo $rollUrl ?>" },
        success: function(response) {
            //Updated log to show the actual response received.
            console.log('Getting response of "' + response + '"');
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

That works for me when I tested without any errors being thrown and the Ajax being executed.

Comment: Miller..! I ran the same code u suggested..! Infact copied pasted it..! But not getting echo. :(

Comment: If it was from before my edit, try again. I had the file named diff on my system. If it was after, be sure you're in the console or change it to an alert.

Comment: yeah..! i changed the file name..! that is ovious. Were u getting echo value??

Comment: "Not working" is the only explanation which "never works"  The script *does* "work" as you have requested, it *does* return the POST'ed refId.  If you are having difficulty experiencing that, then more detail is needed.  BTW: exclamation points are rarely needed on SO to make your point... no one can hear you scream in cyberspace. ;)

Comment: Dude..! chill..! its fine now..! I hv fixed it. Thanks anyways..!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your variable is not set. Use `isset`

```
<?php

$rollUrl=34;
if(isset($_POST['refId'])) {
$refId=$_POST['refId'];
echo $refId;
}

?>
```

**Update**:
You should assign the `refId` as a name attribute to any input field to revive the input from user.

```
<input type="text" name="refId" />
```

Comment: No thats not helping..! Its all just one file.

Comment: check the name of the input field and make sure you have set it to `refId`.

Comment: yeah...! i dont have any input field. Its just the above code.

Comment: You should define `refId` as a name attribute to any field from where you can receive the input from user. see my updated answer

Comment: I am not taking any user input. I want to perform ajax call after a specific function. Input is not required. Assume sending just a key pair values. It should work r8?

Comment: If you want to send nothing from the user then why you are using `$_POST` which is not posting anything in real OR `refID` doesnt exist in any of your code.